# Click on a button to open a file dialog and return the path to text box

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a button and text box. When the user clicks on button the browse dialog gets open, after selecting the file the full path should be written to the text box.
And in second scenario when clicked on the button i should be able to select the folder not the file.
I tried with FileUpload, 
1. I am not able to get the full path from the control 
2. And not able to select a folder
and same with Html file control.

I am working on ASP.NET with VB.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, there's no way to retrieve the file path on the client side. Forget about that.

Comment: Is there a alternative way to do this, as i want the file path selected by the user as an argument to initiate a program

Comment: You could ask the user to type it in.